# What is the proper way to access an object inside state using a key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building an app in React Typescript and I have a state defined like so:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({
    fruits: [],
    veggies: [],
    herbs: [],
  });
```

When I want to add a product from an `HTML select`, let's say a fruit, I will call the following in the `onChange` function:

```
addProduct("fruits", value);
```

Where the function `addProduct` looks something like below. I am using `productType` as a key to access the specific product type in `products`:

```
const addProduct = (productType: string, value: string) => {
  setProducts((products) => ({
    ...products,
    [productType]: [...products.productType, value],
  }));
}
```

However, I am getting this error (screenshot attached to link):
[TS2339: Property 'productType' does not exist on type '{ fruits: never[]; veggies: never[]; herbs: never[]; }'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpUle.png) where `...products.productType` is highlighted.

I've tried accessing `...products.productType` using the dollar sign identifier, template literals but to no avail. How can I access `...products.productType`? Is there a correct syntax to use, or is there a hacky solution around this?

**EDIT:** Thank you for the suggestions on defining the types, I will take that into consideration. However, I think this is the underlying issue:

```
"TS2339: Property 'productType' does not exist on type 'IState'".
```

If I try to access `...products.productType`, it won't let me because `productType` does not exist in my `products` state. How can I get it to search for the string literal (which, in this example, is **"fruits"**)?

Comment: You need to tell TS what type `[]` is when you initially set the state.

Comment: What you looking for is `[productType]: [...products[productType], value],`. There is no property named `productType` and you are trying to access it, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend keeping 3 different states instead of using only one. That will be way more flexible and easy to use and understand (for you and others devs touching your code).

In case you still want to do it that way, what is happening to you is that typescript is `inferring` the types from your initial values, which are empty arrays = `never[]`. To fix this you should type your state like:

```js
interface IState {
  fruits: string[], // use whatever value it should be, I'm just guessing its a string
  veggies: string[],
  herbs: string[],
}

const [products, setProducts] = useState<IState>({
    fruits: [],
    veggies: [],
    herbs: [],
  });


const addProduct = (productType: keyof IState, value: string) => {
  setProducts((products) => ({
    ...products,
    [productType]: [...products[productType], value],
  }));
}
```

**EDIT**: Note that there are 2 more errors

- `producType` should not be of type string but a key of `IState`
- If you access an object with dot notation then TS expects the object to have that exact key. Instead, you should use bracket notation.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. However, I get another error, which I think is the underlying issue, "TS2339: Property 'productType' does not exist on type 'IState'". I am passing productType to addProduct as a key, to identify which value I want to change in the state (fruits, veggies, herbs). It is looking for productType in the state, but I want it to look for the value of productType - fruits. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You have helped OP to clean up his code but your answer doesn't really fixes the issue which OP is asking for  as issue relates to object property access.

Comment: @banhmi123 , I have edited the answer, I hope that helps you clarify everything :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong with your code like @super mentioned, you need to fix those as well. As for reason behind the issue you are getting is because you are trying to access the `productType` property of the old state using `products.productType`.

The property you are trying to access does not exists which is causing the issue and giving you the error.

To access the old states values to concat in value array change your code as below,

```
setProducts((products) => ({
   ...products,
   [productType]: [...products[productType], value],
}));
```

This should fix your issue.

**EDIT**

After change in code to include types for the state object the change was needed is given by @toni's answer.

Comment: Thahnk you, but ...products[productType] will create an error because my state is not an array, it is an object consisting of "fruits" "veggies" and "herbs" :(

Comment: No you will not as you can access object property with `[]` bracket as well. [Here is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) the link for more understanding on this. Did you tried the fix ? Did it give you issue ? What issue did it give ?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yes, I still get this issue: TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IState'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IState'.

I also implemented the change from @Toni Bardina Comas to add types to my state

Comment: Look for @toni's answer he has answered it. You were looking for the `keyOf`.